# SQLite in WPF application

Tags: c#, database, sqlite

I'm trying to use a SQLite database file inside my WPF application.
I tried searching for a proper library that wraps the entire [SQLite](https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki) library.

I found the following [SQLite library](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net) which allows a perfect functionality that suites me.

The problem is building it.
I tried adding it in a Visual Studio as a project and compile it to get a dll file.
That didn't work so much well because of dependencies missing inside the project and sub-projects.
If anyone anticipated or experienced any hard time with this library, I would really use the help and of course appreciate it alot.

Thanks heads up :)

Comment: I have had some problems with SQLite-net PCL and would recommend using sqlite-net-pcl instead. https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net-pcl/1.5.166-beta

Answer (score 5):

You should install it as a nuget package. Right click on your project -> Manage Nuget Packages -> find SQLite.Net-PCL. You don't need source code for this, only released package and that is exactly what nuget will download for you and add as a dependency.

You can also install the package with Visual Studio's Package Manager Console:

```
Install-Package SQLite.Net-PCL
```

If you want to have source code, this library is contained inside a single file, so you can just copy `SQLite.cs` to your project and it will work.